# Internationalization with Django oauth2app?

Tags: django, internationalization, oauth-2.0

I have a Django website where I'm using some of the forms from the oauth2app example site. For example, the user signup form inherits from the Django UserCreationForm.

I want to customize some of the strings that appear in the templated Web pages. As a start, I've investigated the internationalization mechanism in Django.

But I haven't been able to get the strings to change from their defaults. After reading the Django docs, here's what I've done:

- in the Django conf/global_settings.py, I've changed the language in LANGUAGE_CODE to 'fr-fr' (French, just for laughs)
- I've changed LOCALE_PATHS to include full-path-to/contrib/auth/locale
- in the oauth2app example site templates, I've added {% load i18n %}
- Django runs using Apaches FastCGI, so I've restarted the associated Python process

What step have I omitted? Is there a way to debug the issue?

I've made many other changes to the templates, including using CSS to customize their appearance; I see those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the language in my application's settings.py, rather than in the global-settings.py, does the trick.